# How to prevent videos from being clicked before image has disappeared?

Tags: javascript, css, video, youtube, click

or, how do you prevent videos from being clicked from behind an image?

If there is an image in-front of videos, how do you prevent them from being clicked, the videos from behind the image?

What will work here?

First click the close button when it appears on the screen after the curtain goes up.

code https://jsfiddle.net/5abh8Lm1/1/

[image]

Next I am taken to this screen, where I am able to click on the videos behind the image.

How do I prevent that from occurring?

How do you prevent a video from being clicked before the image disappears?

[image]

```css
.splash-screen2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    Background-color: black;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
    opacity: 1;
    /* Set transition duration to 1 seconds */
    pointer-events: none;
    /*dissable mouse clicking */
    cursor: default;
  }
  .splash-screen2.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 10s;
    /* Add a delay of 1 seconds before the opacity changes to 0 */
    pointer-events: none;
    /* Re-enable mouse clicking after 1 seconds */
    cursor: default;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is remove `pointer-events: none;` from both `.splash-screen2` and `.splash-screen2.hide` selectors:

```
...
  .splash-screen2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    ...
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none; /* remove this */
    cursor: default;
  }
  .splash-screen2.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 10s;
    pointer-events: none; /* remove this */
    cursor: default;
  }
...
```

After that, since the videos should appear after the transition end, you can listen to `transitionend` event on the `.splash-screen2` to know if the transition has ended:

```
...
splashScreen2.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
    splashScreen2.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
});
...
```

This way, the pointer will not be blocked on the hidden splash screen until it fully transitioned into hidden.

[Here is the forked jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/ebo7xmwg/)

Comment: Why is it not working here? https://jsfiddle.net/pzoe5c3y/ See: https://i.imgur.com/r29TDBE.png How do I fix that?

Comment: I added: <div class="outer-container"> then it stopped working.

Comment: @EveNinnall you haven't removed the `pointer-events: none;` from the `.splash-screen2` and `.splash-screen2.hide`  css in that jsfiddle, here's the fixed one https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/5ybhsqm6/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, based on your code, is to add some class to `.splash-screen2` after its "disappearance":

```
splashScreen2.classList.add('hide');
setTimeout(() => splashScreen2.classList.add('hide-end'), 10000);
```

And add little css that takes this into account:

```
#myModal:not(:has(.splash-screen2.hide-end)) ~ .containerA,
#myModal:not(:has(.splash-screen2.hide-end)) ~ .containerA *{
   pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Code: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/h4qxugsn/)

Answer (score 0):

you can depend on the transition timing to make the video clickable or not
so in the beginning you can set the point event for the youtube div to be none

```
document.getElementById("myModal").style.pointerEvents="none";
```

then when the transition is finished you can set it back to auto using setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(()=>{
document.getElementById("myModal").style.pointerEvents="auto"
},7000)
```